# Get a message or notification when new mail form is opened?

Tags: c#, outlook-2007, outlook-addin

I need an event/message/notification in an outlook addin, which fires when a new mail form is open by an user? I don't know how to determine which window is opened.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Inspectors.newInspector event which is raised when you open any outlook item in a new window. In the event handlerfor this event, you can check if the Inspector.CurrentItem type is Outlook mail and mail item has isSent as false that means it is an outlook mail item in edit/compose mode.